# Suffix added to plugin name when using wp plugin install <url>

Tags: wp-cli

When I try to install the plugin https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-woocommerce using:

`wp plugin install https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql-woocommerce/releases/download/v0.10.4/wp-graphql-woocommerce.zip`

The plugin will be added with a random suffix added to the plugin-name
`/wp-content/plugins/wp-graphql-woocommerce-0ymkp2`.

Is this by design or is something weird going on? Currently I am using curl to download the package and install it from the local file.

Comment: Hi Dennie, I am also facing the same issue. Did you get any solution to this problem.

I am installing the plugin from a local zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I was creating a custom plugin.  It appears to happen because Wordpress expects a subdirectory at the root of the plugin's `.zip` file that matches the slug of the plugin.

That is, instead of the `.zip` file containing:

```
includes/class-acf-schema-filters.php
includes/class-core-schema-filters.php
.
.
.
vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/Key.php
vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php   
wp-graphql-woocommerce.php
```

It should instead contain:

```
wp-graphql-woocommerce/includes/class-acf-schema-filters.php
wp-graphql-woocommerce/includes/class-core-schema-filters.php
.
.
.
wp-graphql-woocommerce/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/Key.php
wp-graphql-woocommerce/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php   
wp-graphql-woocommerce/wp-graphql-woocommerce.php
```

As soon as I changed my plugin to have a subdirectory at the root of the `.zip` file, Wordpress stopped renaming my plugin directory with a random suffix whenever I updated it.